# 'ng' is not recognized after remove and reinstall

Tags: angular, npm, angular13, npm-cache

[image]

```
npm -g list command I can see installed Angular globally but when I run the ng --version it is giving   
this error ng: The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ng --version
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ng:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have deleted node and npm from my pc and reinstalled them, but it is still not working.

Comment: also I have updated Environment Variables

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the version of the npm package instead. What you typed means you are asking it to check the version by running angular installed as a program on the computer, not an npm package. The command you want is `npm list ng --depth=0`. This gives you the version installed with npm. It takes it out of the list command you were using.

https://nodejs.dev/learn/find-the-installed-version-of-an-npm-package

If you want to be able to use angular from the command line, you need to install angular-cli as well.

Comment: Thank you for helping me,  I have run npm list ng --depth=0 command it was showing me this " User@ C:\Users\User
`-- (empty) "

Answer (score 0):

First: Install CLI by writing->>>: npm install -g @angular/cli
Second:if you want check your version writing -->>>: **`*ng v OR ng version*`**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: facing the same issue, were you able to figure this out?